# Social Customer Service’s full default Apex class code not able to be saved/created

Tags: apex, winter19, social-studio, social-customer-service

After configuring Social Studio and Social Post.

Getting this error below :

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: postLabels at line 472 column 17

When running the default code from the [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=social_customer_service_apexclass_ref.htm&type=5):

```
global virtual class InboundSocialPostHandlerImpl implements Social.InboundSocialPostHandler {

final static Integer CONTENT_MAX_LENGTH = SocialPost.Content.getDescribe().getLength();
final static Integer SUBJECT_MAX_LENGTH = Case.Subject.getDescribe().getLength();
Boolean isNewCaseCreated = false;

// Reopen case if it has not been closed for more than this number
global virtual Integer getMaxNumberOfDaysClosedToReopenCase() {
    return 5;
}

// Create a case if one of these post labels are on the SocialPost, regardless of the skipCreateCase indicator.
global virtual Set<String> getPostLabelsThatCreateCase(){
    return new Set<String>();
}

// If true, use the active case assignment rule if one is found
global virtual Boolean getUsingCaseAssignmentRule(){
    return false;
}

global virtual String getDefaultAccountId() {
    return null;
}

global virtual String getCaseSubject(SocialPost post) {
    String caseSubject = post.Name;
    if (hasReview(post)) {
        String ratingsStr = getRatingString(post);
        caseSubject = ratingsStr + ' • ' + caseSubject;
    }

    return caseSubject;
}

global Social.InboundSocialPostResult handleInboundSocialPost(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona, Map<String, Object> rawData) {
    Social.InboundSocialPostResult result = new Social.InboundSocialPostResult();
    result.setSuccess(true);
    matchPost(post);
    matchPersona(persona);

    if ((post.Content != null) && (post.Content.length() > CONTENT_MAX_LENGTH)) {
        post.Content = post.Content.abbreviate(CONTENT_MAX_LENGTH);
    }

    if (post.Id != null) {
        handleExistingPost(post, persona);
        return result;
    }

    setReplyTo(post, persona);
    buildPersona(persona);
    Case parentCase = buildParentCase(post, persona, rawData);
    setRelationshipsOnPost(post, persona, parentCase);
    setModeration(post, rawData);

    upsert post;

    if(isNewCaseCreated){
        updateCaseSource(post, parentCase);
    }

    handlePostAttachments(post, rawData);

    return result;
}

private void setModeration(SocialPost post, Map<String, Object> rawData){
    //if we don't automatically create a case, we should flag the post as requiring moderator review.
    if(post.parentId == null && !isUnsentParent(rawData))
        post.reviewedStatus = 'Needed';
}

private void updateCaseSource(SocialPost post, Case parentCase){
    if(parentCase != null) {
        parentCase.SourceId = post.Id;
        //update as a new sobject to prevent undoing any changes done by insert triggers
        update new Case(Id = parentCase.Id, SourceId = parentCase.SourceId);
    }

}

private void handleExistingPost(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
        List<SocialPost> existingPosts = [Select Recipient, IsOutbound from SocialPost where id = :post.Id limit 1];

        // for any existing outbound post, we don't overwrite its recipient field
        if (!existingPosts.isEmpty() && existingPosts[0].IsOutBound == true && String.isNotBlank(existingPosts[0].Recipient)) {
            post.Recipient = existingPosts[0].Recipient;
        }

        update post;
        if (persona.id != null)
            updatePersona(persona);
}

private void setReplyTo(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
    SocialPost replyTo = findReplyTo(post, persona);
    if(replyTo.id != null) {
        post.replyToId = replyTo.id;
        post.replyTo = replyTo;
    }
}

private SocialPersona buildPersona(SocialPersona persona) {
    if (persona.Id == null)
        createPersona(persona);
    else
        updatePersona(persona);

    return persona;
}

private void updatePersona(SocialPersona persona) {
    try{
        update persona;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug('Error updating social persona: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private Case buildParentCase(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona, Map<String, Object> rawData){
    if(!isUnsentParent(rawData)) {
        Case parentCase = findParentCase(post, persona);
        if (parentCase != null) {
            if (!parentCase.IsClosed) {
                return parentCase;
            }
            else if (caseShouldBeReopened(parentCase)) {
                reopenCase(parentCase);
                return parentCase;
            }
        }
        if(shouldCreateCase(post, rawData)){
            isNewCaseCreated = true;
            return createCase(post, persona);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private boolean caseShouldBeReopened(Case c){
    return c.id != null && c.isClosed && System.now() < c.closedDate.addDays(getMaxNumberOfDaysClosedToReopenCase());
}

private void setRelationshipsOnPost(SocialPost postToUpdate, SocialPersona persona, Case parentCase) {
    if (persona.Id != null) {
        postToUpdate.PersonaId = persona.Id;

        if(persona.ParentId.getSObjectType() != SocialPost.sObjectType) {
            postToUpdate.WhoId = persona.ParentId;
        }
    }
    if(parentCase != null) {
        postToUpdate.ParentId = parentCase.Id;
    }
}

private Boolean hasReview(SocialPost post) {
    return post.ReviewScore != null;
}

private String getRatingString(SocialPost post) {
    Integer maxNumberOfStars = 5;
    Double reviewScore = post.ReviewScore;
    Double reviewScale = post.ReviewScale;
    if (reviewScore == null) {
        reviewScore = 0;
    }
    if (reviewScale == null) {
        reviewScale = maxNumberOfStars;
    }
    Integer numberOfStars = Math.floor((reviewScore / reviewScale) * maxNumberOfStars).intValue();
    return numberOfStars.format() + '-Star';
}

private Case createCase(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
    String caseSubject = getCaseSubject(post).abbreviate(SUBJECT_MAX_LENGTH);

    Case newCase = new Case(subject = caseSubject);
    if (persona != null && persona.ParentId != null) {
        if (persona.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Contact.sObjectType) {
            newCase.ContactId = persona.ParentId;
        } else if (persona.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Account.sObjectType) {
            newCase.AccountId = persona.ParentId;
        }
    }
    if (post != null && post.Provider != null) {
        newCase.Origin = post.Provider;
    }

    if (getUsingCaseAssignmentRule()){
        //Find the active assignment rules on case
        AssignmentRule[] rules = [select id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Case' and Active = true limit 1];

        if (rules.size() > 0){
            //Creating the DMLOptions for "Assign using active assignment rules" checkbox
            Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
            dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId= rules[0].id;

            //Setting the DMLOption on Case instance
            newCase.setOptions(dmlOpts);
        }
    }

    insert newCase;
    return newCase;
}

private Case findParentCase(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
        Case parentCase = null;
        if (!isChat(post) && (isReplyingToOutboundPost(post) && isSocialPostRecipientSameAsPersona(post.ReplyTo, persona)) || (!isReplyingToOutboundPost(post) && isReplyingToSelf(post,persona))) {
            parentCase = findParentCaseFromPostReply(post);
            if (isParentCaseValid(parentCase)) { 
            return parentCase;
        }
        }

    parentCase = findParentCaseFromPersonaAndRecipient(post, persona);
    if (parentCase == null && isChat(post)) {
        parentCase = findParentCaseOfChatFromPersonaAndRecipient(post, persona);    
    }
    return parentCase;
}

private boolean isChat(SocialPost post) {
    return post.messageType == 'Private' || post.messageType == 'Direct';
}

private boolean isParentCaseValid(Case parentCase) {
    return parentCase != null && (!parentCase.IsClosed || caseShouldBeReopened(parentCase));
}

private Case findParentCaseFromPostReply(SocialPost post) {
    if (post.ReplyTo != null && String.isNotBlank(post.ReplyTo.ParentId)) {
        List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, IsClosed, Status, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE Id = :post.ReplyTo.ParentId LIMIT 1];
        if(!cases.isEmpty()) {
            return cases[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// reply to outbound post
private boolean isReplyingToOutboundPost(SocialPost post) {
        return (post != null && post.ReplyTo != null && post.ReplyTo.IsOutbound);
}

// replyTo.recipient == inboundSocialPost.persona.externalId
private boolean isSocialPostRecipientSameAsPersona(SocialPost postWithRecipient, SocialPersona persona) {
        return (postWithRecipient != null && postWithRecipient.Recipient == persona.ExternalId);
}

// is replying to self
private boolean isReplyingToSelf(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
        return (post != null && 
                persona != null && 
                String.isNotBlank(persona.Id) && 
                post.ReplyTo != null &&
                String.isNotBlank(post.ReplyTo.PersonaId) &&
                post.ReplyTo.PersonaId == persona.id);
}

private Case findParentCaseFromPersona(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
    SocialPost lastestInboundPostWithSamePersona = findLatestInboundPostBasedOnPersona(post, persona);
    if (lastestInboundPostWithSamePersona != null) {
        List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, IsClosed, Status, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE id = :lastestInboundPostWithSamePersona.parentId LIMIT 1];
        if(!cases.isEmpty()) {
            return cases[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private Case findParentCaseFromPersonaAndRecipient(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
    SocialPost lastestInboundPostWithSamePersonaAndRecipient = findLatestInboundPostBasedOnPersonaAndRecipient(post, persona);
    if (lastestInboundPostWithSamePersonaAndRecipient != null) {
        List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, IsClosed, Status, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE id = :lastestInboundPostWithSamePersonaAndRecipient.parentId LIMIT 1];
        if(!cases.isEmpty()) {
            return cases[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private Case findParentCaseOfChatFromPersonaAndRecipient(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
    SocialPost lastestReplyToPost = findLatestOutboundReplyToPostBasedOnPersonaAndRecipient(post, persona);
    if (lastestReplyToPost != null) {
        List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, IsClosed, Status, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE id = :lastestReplyToPost.parentId LIMIT 1];
        if(!cases.isEmpty()) {
            return cases[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void reopenCase(Case parentCase) {
    SObject[] status = [SELECT MasterLabel FROM CaseStatus WHERE IsClosed = false AND IsDefault = true];
    parentCase.Status = ((CaseStatus)status[0]).MasterLabel;
    update parentCase;
}

private void matchPost(SocialPost post) {
        if (post.Id != null) return;

    performR6PostIdCheck(post);

    if (post.Id == null){
        performExternalPostIdCheck(post);
    }
}


private void performR6PostIdCheck(SocialPost post){
    if(post.R6PostId == null) return;
    List<SocialPost> postList = [SELECT Id FROM SocialPost WHERE R6PostId = :post.R6PostId LIMIT 1];
    if (!postList.isEmpty()) {
        post.Id = postList[0].Id;
    }
}


private void performExternalPostIdCheck(SocialPost post) {
    if (post.provider == 'Facebook' && post.messageType == 'Private') return;
    if (post.provider == null || post.externalPostId == null) return;
    List<SocialPost> postList = [SELECT Id FROM SocialPost WHERE ExternalPostId = :post.ExternalPostId AND Provider = :post.provider LIMIT 1];
    if (!postList.isEmpty()) {
        post.Id = postList[0].Id;
    }
}


private SocialPost findReplyTo(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
    if(post.replyToId != null && post.replyTo == null)
        return findReplyToBasedOnReplyToId(post);
    if(post.responseContextExternalId != null){
        if((post.provider == 'Facebook' && post.messageType == 'Private') || (post.provider == 'Twitter' && post.messageType == 'Direct')) {
            SocialPost replyTo = findReplyToBasedOnResponseContextExternalPostIdAndProvider(post);
            if(replyTo.id != null) 
                return replyTo;
        }
        return findReplyToBasedOnExternalPostIdAndProvider(post);
    }
    return new SocialPost();
}

private SocialPost findReplyToBasedOnReplyToId(SocialPost post){
    List<SocialPost> posts = [SELECT Id, ParentId, IsOutbound, PersonaId, Recipient FROM SocialPost WHERE id = :post.replyToId LIMIT 1];
    if(posts.isEmpty())
        return new SocialPost();
    return posts[0];
}

private SocialPost findReplyToBasedOnExternalPostIdAndProvider(SocialPost post){
    List<SocialPost> posts = [SELECT Id, ParentId, IsOutbound, PersonaId, Recipient FROM SocialPost WHERE Provider = :post.provider AND ExternalPostId = :post.responseContextExternalId LIMIT 1];
    if(posts.isEmpty())
        return new SocialPost();
    return posts[0];
}

private SocialPost findReplyToBasedOnResponseContextExternalPostIdAndProvider(SocialPost post){
    List<SocialPost> posts = [SELECT Id, ParentId, IsOutbound, PersonaId FROM SocialPost WHERE Provider = :post.provider AND Recipient = :post.Recipient AND responseContextExternalId = :post.responseContextExternalId ORDER BY posted DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1];
    if(posts.isEmpty())
        return new SocialPost();
    return posts[0];
}

private SocialPost findLatestInboundPostBasedOnPersonaAndRecipient(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
    if (persona != null && String.isNotBlank(persona.Id) && post != null && String.isNotBlank(post.Recipient)) {
        List<SocialPost> posts = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM SocialPost WHERE Provider = :post.provider AND Recipient = :post.Recipient AND PersonaId = :persona.id AND IsOutbound = false ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
        if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
            return posts[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private SocialPost findLatestInboundPostBasedOnPersona(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
    if (persona != null && String.isNotBlank(persona.Id) && post != null) {
        List<SocialPost> posts = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM SocialPost WHERE Provider = :post.provider AND PersonaId = :persona.id AND IsOutbound = false ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
        if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
            return posts[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private SocialPost findLatestOutboundReplyToPostBasedOnPersonaAndRecipient(SocialPost post, SocialPersona persona) {
    if (persona != null && String.isNotBlank(persona.Id) && post != null) {
            List<ExternalSocialAccount> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM ExternalSocialAccount WHERE ExternalAccountId = :post.Recipient];
        if (!accounts.isEmpty()) {
                ExternalSocialAccount account = accounts[0];
            List<SocialPost> posts = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM SocialPost WHERE Provider = :post.provider AND Recipient = :persona.ExternalId AND OutboundSocialAccountId = :account.Id AND IsOutbound = true ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
            if (!posts.isEmpty()) {
                return posts[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void matchPersona(SocialPersona persona) {
    if (persona != null) {
        List<SocialPersona> personaList = new List<SocialPersona>();
        if (persona.Provider != 'Other') {
            if (String.isNotBlank(persona.ExternalId)) {
                personaList = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM SocialPersona WHERE
                    Provider = :persona.Provider AND
                    ExternalId = :persona.ExternalId LIMIT 1];
            }
            else if (String.isNotBlank(persona.Name)) {
                //this is a best-effort attempt to match: persona.Name is not guaranteed to be unique for all networks
                personaList = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM SocialPersona WHERE
                    Provider = :persona.Provider AND
                    Name = :persona.Name LIMIT 1];
            }
        }
        else if(persona.Provider == 'Other' && String.isNotBlank(persona.ExternalId) && String.isNotBlank(persona.MediaProvider)) {
            personaList = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM SocialPersona WHERE
                MediaProvider = :persona.MediaProvider AND
                ExternalId = :persona.ExternalId LIMIT 1];
        } else if(persona.Provider == 'Other' && String.isNotBlank(persona.Name) && String.isNotBlank(persona.MediaProvider)) {
            personaList = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM SocialPersona WHERE
                MediaProvider = :persona.MediaProvider AND
                Name = :persona.Name LIMIT 1];
        }

        if (!personaList.isEmpty()) {
            persona.Id = personaList[0].Id;
            persona.ParentId = personaList[0].ParentId;
        }
    }
}

private void createPersona(SocialPersona persona) {
    if (persona == null || String.isNotBlank(persona.Id) || !isThereEnoughInformationToCreatePersona(persona))
        return;

    SObject parent = createPersonaParent(persona);
    persona.ParentId = parent.Id;
    insert persona;
}

private boolean isThereEnoughInformationToCreatePersona(SocialPersona persona) {
    return String.isNotBlank(persona.Name) && 
           String.isNotBlank(persona.Provider) && 
           String.isNotBlank(persona.MediaProvider);
}

private boolean shouldCreateCase(SocialPost post, Map<String, Object> rawData) {
    return !isUnsentParent(rawData) && (!hasSkipCreateCaseIndicator(rawData) || hasPostLabelsThatCreateCase(post));
}

private boolean isUnsentParent(Map<String, Object> rawData) {
    Object unsentParent = rawData.get('unsentParent');
    return unsentParent != null && 'true'.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(unsentParent));
}

private boolean hasSkipCreateCaseIndicator(Map<String, Object> rawData) {
    Object skipCreateCase = rawData.get('skipCreateCase');
    return skipCreateCase != null && 'true'.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(skipCreateCase));
}

private boolean hasPostLabelsThatCreateCase(SocialPost post){
    Set<String> postLabels = getPostLabels(post);
    postLabels.retainAll(getPostLabelsThatCreateCase());
    return !postLabels.isEmpty();
}

private Set<String> getPostLabels(SocialPost post){
    Set<String> postLabels = new Set<String>();
    if(post.postLabels != null)
        postLabels.addAll(post.postLabels.split(',', 0));
    return postLabels;
}

global String getPersonaFirstName(SocialPersona persona) {
    String name = getPersonaName(persona);      
    String firstName = '';
    if (name.contains(' ')) {
        firstName = name.substringBeforeLast(' ');
    }
    firstName = firstName.abbreviate(40);
    return firstName;
}

global String getPersonaLastName(SocialPersona persona) {   
    String name = getPersonaName(persona);   
    String lastName = name;
    if (name.contains(' ')) {
        lastName = name.substringAfterLast(' ');
    }
    lastName = lastName.abbreviate(80);
    return lastName;
}

private String getPersonaName(SocialPersona persona) {
    String name = persona.Name.trim();
    if (String.isNotBlank(persona.RealName)) {
        name = persona.RealName.trim();
    }
    return name;
}

global virtual SObject createPersonaParent(SocialPersona persona) {
    String firstName = getPersonaFirstName(persona);
    String lastName = getPersonaLastName(persona);

    Contact contact = new Contact(LastName = lastName, FirstName = firstName);
    String defaultAccountId = getDefaultAccountId();
    if (defaultAccountId != null)
        contact.AccountId = defaultAccountId;
    insert contact;
    return contact;
}

private void handlePostAttachments(SocialPost post, Map<String, Object> rawData) {
    String attachmentRawData = JSON.serialize(rawData.get('mediaUrls'));
    if (String.isNotBlank(attachmentRawData)) {
        List<PostAttachment> attachments = (List<PostAttachment>) JSON.deserialize(attachmentRawData, List<PostAttachment>.class);
        if (attachments != null && !attachments.isEmpty()) {
            createAttachments(post, attachments);
        }
    }
}

private void createAttachments(SocialPost post, List<PostAttachment> attachments) {
    List<ContentVersion> contentVersions = new List<ContentVersion>();
    for(PostAttachment attachment : attachments) {
        if (String.isNotBlank(attachment.mediaUrl) && attachment.mediaUrl != null && attachment.mediaUrl.length() <= ContentVersion.ContentUrl.getDescribe().getLength()) {
            ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion();
            contentVersion.contentUrl = attachment.mediaUrl;
            contentVersion.contentLocation = 'L';
            contentVersions.add(contentVersion);
        }
    }
    if (!contentVersions.isEmpty()) {
        insert(contentVersions);
        createLinksForAttachmentsToSocialPost(post, contentVersions);
    }
}

private void createLinksForAttachmentsToSocialPost(SocialPost post, List<ContentVersion> contentVersions) {
    List<Id> versionIds = new List<Id>(new Map<Id, ContentVersion>(contentVersions).keySet());
    List<ContentDocument> contentDocuments = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE LatestPublishedVersionId IN :versionIds];
    List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
    for(ContentDocument contentDocument : contentDocuments) {
        ContentDocumentLink contentDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
        contentDocLink.contentDocumentId = contentDocument.Id;
        contentDocLink.linkedEntityId = post.Id;
        contentDocLink.shareType = 'I';
        contentDocLink.visibility = 'AllUsers';
        contentDocumentLinks.add(contentDocLink);
    }
    if (!contentDocumentLinks.isEmpty()) {
        insert(contentDocumentLinks);
    }
}

public class PostAttachment {
    public String mediaType;
    public String mediaUrl;

    public PostAttachment(String mediaType, String mediaUrl) {
        this.mediaType = mediaType;
        this.mediaUrl = mediaUrl;
    }
}
```

}

Is this a bug or is the default code wrong?

Comment: Do you have Social Studio? If not, you wouldn't have access to the object, and this is the error you'd see. I'm not sure how to get this enabled, though, so you might want to contact support or your account executive.

Comment: Ah thx, I've managed to enable Social Studio. Will update the question